# iPhone : Unable to copy from MainBundle to NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: iphone, file-io, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I am trying to copy a couple of image files from my MainBundle/SampleImages folder to the application NSDocumentDirectory/Library folder, but am unable to do so. I have checked that the images are in .app/Mainbundle/SampleImages directory and I have also checked that the Library folder is being created in the NSDocumentsDirectory, but no files are copied.

I have tried two approaches, given below, but with no success.
here is the code that I am using to copy files.

**First Method**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];     
        NSString *documentLibraryFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"];

        NSString *resourceSampleImagesFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleImages"];
        NSData *mainBundleFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:resourceSampleImagesFolderPath];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentLibraryFolderPath
                                                contents:mainBundleFile 
                                              attributes:nil];
```

**Second Method**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];     
        NSString *documentSampleImagesFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"];

        NSString *resourceSampleImagesFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleImages/"];
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: documentSampleImagesFolderPath attributes:nil];
        if([fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceSampleImagesFolderPath toPath:documentSampleImagesFolderPath error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"success");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Failure");
            NSLog(@"%d",error);
        }
```

I have spent a couple of hours looking for a solution, any help here would be appreciated greatly.

Thank You

Shumais Ul Haq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it done with the second method by changing it  bit.
There is no need for creating the directory as the SDK docs say that the destination directory must not exist.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"];

        NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleImages"];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
```

Comment: useless: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260  ... file not exists